# Exchange 2010, Outlook 2013 - Shared my account and tasks/calendar, but other user can't see all tasks

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2013

I use exchange 2010 at the office and we have outlook 2013 clients. I want to share my emails and calendar and tasks. So I set that up the usual way through outlook, but the other user only sees about half of my tasks. They see the emails and calendar just fine.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Are any of your tasks marked as "Private" (an icon with a lock)? If yes, then when sharing a task, calendar event or anything else marked "Private" will not be seen by others.

This is good when you have dentist or doctor appointments that you don't want shared with others.